# Why excel keeps asking me to save when closing App?

Tags: c#, excel, winforms

I have a WFA that manages a local database held in Excel, for some reason, the application ask to save the workbook when closing even though I didn't modify it; *When using the Excel Interop v 12.0.0.0* without deploying my application I have no issues when I close it, it works perfectly fine, however, *I had it deployed using Excel Interop v 16.0.0.0* and it keeps to asking to save when closing, or after making a change (this behavior it's impossible to replicate using the v 12 of the Interop using exactly the same code I wrote between versions).

This is the code I use to close my application by button:

```
try
{
    oXL.Application.IgnoreRemoteRequests = false;
    oWB.Close();
    {
        if
        (oXL.Workbooks.Count < 1)
        {
            oXL.Quit();
        }
    }
}
catch (Exception)
{
    MessageBox.Show("La base de datos no se pudo cerrar correctamente, verifique que su informacion no se haya perdido.", "ERROR AL CERRAR DB", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
}
this.Close();
```

I made this to try to fix it:

```
try
{
    oXL.Application.IgnoreRemoteRequests = false;
    oWB.Save();
    oWB.Close();
    {
        if
        (oXL.Workbooks.Count < 1)
        {
            oXL.Quit();
        }
    }
}
catch (Exception)
{
    MessageBox.Show("La base de datos no se pudo cerrar correctamente, verifique que su informacion no se haya perdido.", "ERROR AL CERRAR DB", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
}
this.Close();
```

However, no luck and the program still ask to save when using Interop v 16.
Can anyone explain what's happening?

**Note: When the app is running, whenever I do anything, I made it save programmatically without asking.**

Answer (score 0):

Not an explanation, but IF you are sure that all relevant changes are already persisted, just disregard further changes on closing:

```
workbook.Close(SaveChanges: XlSaveAction.xlDoNotSaveChanges);
```

Comment: This would be useful in said case, as you can see on the first example, I close without saving, however, this wouldn't help me to prevent the dialog with the constant updates we do to the database. Any other suggestion?